# How expensive is accessing Match.group()?

Tags: python, regex, optimization

Trying to optimize some code that reuses a matched group, I was wondering whether accessing `Match.group()` is expensive. I tried to dig in [re.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/re.py)'s source, but the code was a bit cryptic.

A few tests seem to indicate that it might be better to store the output of `Match.group()` in a variable, but I would like to understand what exactly happens when `Match.group()` is called, and if there is another internal way to maybe access the content of the group directly.

Some example code to illustrate a potential use:

```py
import re

m = re.search('X+', f'__{"X"*10000}__')

# do something
# m.group()

# do something else
# m.group()
```

###### Timings

direct access:

```py
%%timeit
len(m.group())
220 ns ± 1.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

intermediate variable:

```py
X = m.group()
```

```py
%%timeit
len(X)
# 51 ns ± 0.172 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

References:
[current re.py code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/re.py) (python 3.10)
[current sre_compile.py code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/sre_compile.py) (python 3.10)

removing the effect of attribute access (doesn't change much)

```py
G = m.group

%%timeit
len(G())
230 ns ± 1.12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is directly related to `Match.group()` and not just a case of [Why is local variable access faster than class member access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397984/why-is-local-variable-access-faster-than-class-member-access-in-python) ?

Comment: Also, I didn't thoroughly go over `re`'s code, but if `group()` is a function/method then it makes perfect sense that calling it multiple times will have an overhead over just calling it once. A better test would be to save a reference to it (`x = match.group`) and then time the calls to `x()`.

Comment: @DeepSpace nice suggestion, I tried it and it doesn't change much the timing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The match object holds a reference to the original string you searched in, and indexes where each group starts and ends, including group 0, the whole matched string. Every call to `group()` slices the original string to create a new string to return.

Saving the return value to a variable avoids the time and memory cost of having to slice the string every time. (It also avoids repeating the method call overhead.)

You can see that `group()` isn't just returning a cached string by the fact that the return value isn't always the same object:

```py
>>> import re
>>> x = re.search(r'sd', 'asdf')
>>> x.group() is x.group()
False
```

If you want to see the implementation of `group()`, it's [`match_group`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/_sre.c#L2087) in `Modules/_sre.c` in the Python source code.

Answer (score 1):

`.group` might be used to access whole match (when no arguments are provided) or certain group (when number of it is given) for example

```
import re
m = re.match('(X)X+','XXXXX')
print(m.group(1)) # output X
```

Note that `re.Match` instances have `.string` which you might access to full string, that is

```
import re
m = re.match('(X)X+','XXXXX')
print(m.string) # output XXXXX
```